# Can Excel automatically adjust cell contents to retain a consecutive pattern?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel

I'm typing a string of consecutive numbers in individual cells.

After completing the string, I go back and delete the contents of one of the cells in the column.

Is there a way that Excel can then automatically adjust the numbers in the rest of the column so that they remain consecutive?

For instance:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Then I delete the value (but not the cell) `2`

Can Excel adjust the rest of the numbers so it looks like this:

```
1

2
3
4
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you just trying to insert a blank cell? If you have:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

and you want it to be

```
1

2
3
4
5
```

just select (click on) the cell with `2` in it, right-click, select `Insert...`, and pick `Shift cells down`.

### **EDIT**

There is also a way to do this using the [**`IF`**](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/if-HP005209118.aspx) formula, used like so:

```
=IF(logical_test, [value_if_true], [value_if_false])
```

Here are the first 3 cells in the column (assuming we're at the top of column `A`):

```
    A
   --------
1 |1
2 |2
3 |=IF(A2=0,A1+1,A2+1)
```

After this, click on cell `A3`, grab the "handle" in the bottom-right, and drag it down to fill in the rest of your column (or, click on `A3`, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to copy the formula, select the cells you want to fill, and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> to paste). You'll then be able to delete any number and the list will continue below it. However, beware adding other data into the deleted cell, as that may interfere with the calculations.

Comment: I'm typing a string of consecutive numbers in individual cells.

After completing the string, I go back and delete the contents of one of the cells in the column.

Is there a way that Excel can then automatically adjust the numbers in the rest of the column so that they remain consecutive?

For instance (commas delimit cells): 1,2,3,4,5

Then I delete the value (but not the cell) 2.

Can Excel adjust the rest of the numbers so it looks like this: 1, ,2,3,4
 this is the correct question...? pls give me a solution for this question..

Comment: @theepan please see my edit above

Comment: thank you but this is not suitable because if I delete more than 1 cell continuously this order will change, again it will start from 1 according to our formula, but what I need is if I delete more than 1 number ( not limited to 2) also this order will not change,

Comment: @theepan - can I ask exactly what you're trying to do? Why enter numbers if you're just going to delete them? It seems like my original answer of inserting empty cells would work just as well.

Answer (score 2):

Enter `1` in the top cell in the column –– let’s call it `S1`.  Then enter `=MAX(S$1:S1) + 1` into `S2` and drag/fill it down as far as you want/need to go.  `S$1` *always* refers to cell `S1`, whereas `S1` will be transformed by the drag/fill process to refer to the cell above the current one. 
For example, `S7` will contain `=MAX(S$1:S6) + 1`. 
So, this formula looks at all the cells in this column (`S`) above the current one,
finds the highest value, and adds one. 
As MattDMo points out, typing other values into the column may produce undesired results.

Answer (score 2):

In MS Excel 2007 & 2010, here's a way to readjust the series even without formulas. It's not automatic, but it won't take you more than a minute to do it.

Let's say you have a series of numbers entered in **A1:A10**.

1. Delete the values or clear any of the cells.
2. To select the remaining values, highlight the entire column, press <kbd>F5</kbd>, click **Special** and then choose **Constants**. Click **Ok**.

   [image]
3. Under the Home tab, click **Fill** > **Series** (or press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, <kbd>F</kbd>, <kbd>I</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd>). Select **Linear** and set the **Step Value** to `1`. Click **Ok**.

   [image]

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Theepan,

I believe what you're looking for would only be possible if you write some VB script or code for a spreadsheet.

So far as I am aware, Excel has no function for automatically maintaining consecutive numerals in non-consecutive cells. This would normally be done manually by the user.

If you simply want to insert an empty or blank cell inside an otherwise consecutive list, you'll need to do what MattDMo suggests, which is to insert a cell, which would maintain the consecutive list while retaining the new blank cell.

Comment: check out my edit - it looks like a simple **`IF`** statement should do the trick...

Comment: Yes, he'll need to use some code. Simple code, but code nonetheless. Which means that if he's trying to do this across multiple sheets frequently, it'll be a problem, but if he's just needing this capability on a single worksheet, it won't be too difficult to build and reuse.

Comment: @music2myear can u guide me how to write this code. is it hard?